# Dataset in controller has values but response is missing values in browser - ASP.NET Core MVC & Ajax

Tags: c#, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-6.0

[Edit]:

My dtp_result structure is: {draw: 1, error: null, data: {}}
the details of **data** are shown in below image..that should be bound to the table...

Adding dataset being returned:

[image]

[image]

[Original Question]:

The dataset being returned by the controller has all values but in chrome Response the values are all empty..therefore the datatable looks as follows

[image]

The dataset returned from controller has all the data, but when analysed in browser its all empty:

{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":5934,"recordsFiltered":5934,"data":[{"id":[],"ingest_id":[],"state_name":[],"vehicle_name":[],"start_time":[],"end_time":[],"distance_km":[]},{"id":[],"ingest_id":[],"state_name":[],"vehicle_name":[],"start_time":[],"end_time":[],"distance_km":[]},{"id":[],"ingest_id":[],"state_name":[],"vehicle_name":[],"start_time":[],"end_time":[],"distance_km":[]},{"id":[],"ingest_id":[],"state_name":[],"vehicle_name":[],"start_time":[],"end_time":[],"distance_km":[]},{"id":[],"ingest_id":[],"state_name":[],"vehicle_name":[],"start_time":[],"end_time":[],"distance_km":[]},{"id":[],"ingest_id":[],"state_name":[],"vehicle_name":[],"start_time":[],"end_time":[],"distance_km":[]},{"id":[],"ingest_id":[],"state_name":[],"vehicle_name":[],"start_time":[],"end_time":[],"distance_km":[]},{"id":[],"ingest_id":[],"state_name":[],"vehicle_name":[],"start_time":[],"end_time":[],"distance_km":[]},{"id":[],"ingest_id":[],"state_name":[],"vehicle_name":[],"start_time":[],"end_time":[],"distance_km":[]},{"id":[],"ingest_id":[],"state_name":[],"vehicle_name":[],"start_time":[],"end_time":[],"distance_km":[]}],"error":null}

Here is my code:

```
[Route("api/gettd")]
public DataTableResultPageGeneric GetTD([FromQuery] DataTableParameters dtp)
{
        logger.Info("Web API:  GET api/gettd");

        //fetch data from db
        return dtp_result;
}
```

Ajax call:

```
track_table = $('#cavtrdatatable').DataTable({

"ajax": {
        "url": CAV_TRACK_DATA_URI,
        "data": {}
    },
    "processing": true,
    "autoWidth": false, // need this to handle rendering issues in bootstrap and during re-size.  Note handlers at end of page.
    "scrollX": true, // for when the widget gets too small
    "language": {
        "processing": '<span style="width:100%;"><img src="/Content/icons/ajax-loader-orange-med.gif" /></span>'
    },
    "serverSide": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]], // might restrict to a max page size, don't allow ALL (-1)
    "drawCallback": function (settings) {
        if (clickFirstRow) {

            $('#cavptdatatable').DataTable().search('');
            $('#cavtrdatatable tbody td').click();
            clickFirstRow = false;
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "id",
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        {
            "data": "state_name",
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        {
            "data": "vehicle_name",
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        {
            "data": "start_time",
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        {
            "data": "end_time",
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        {
            "data": "distance_km",
            "defaultContent": ''
        }
    ],
    "order": [[0, 'asc']]  // can specify different default ordering
});
```

Some background information: I am migrating an ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.6.1) application to ASP.NET Core 6.0..An existing api ajax call stopped working, to fix that I have made below changes:

- `FromQuery` instead of `FromUri`
- The datatableParameter was nested object and did not work with `FromQuery` so I implemented as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69810222/datatables-net-and-asp-net-core-webapi-get-searchvalue) link

Now using HttpContext I am able to load data and the controller returns it but the data is empty..

Comment: Ensure you are fetching the data from the db. If you are, check the HTTP response you get in the browser from the network tab of the developer tools. If the two things are different, then you are having issue in the JSON serialization of the controller. This is actually done by the framework. Post a well formatted example of the dataset you fetch from the db and the HTTP response content that you get in the browser.

Comment: okay that might answer! because both Are different. I will post the dataset now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently Enrico's comment and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58127214/net-core-3-0-webapi-jsonserialize-does-not-serialize-nested-objects-all-objec) post lead me to the solution.

I added NewtonsoftJson nuget package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

and then added following to the Startup class.

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

After which the Serialization happened properly.